# Identify variation patterns in image time series

Tags: image-processing, wavelet, time-series, discrete-wavelet-transform, pywavelets

I am working on time series of 12 remote sensing images obtained at irregular intervals. The pixels of all images are of exact same region. Pixels of some areas in these images vary in time with standard deviation (SD) as high as 1.17 while others vary as low as SD 0.08. There is also certain amount of noise associated with each image which can contribute temporal changes. The objective is to identify highly varying pixels from the less varying ones using the original time series of images. 
I could be wrong here but my approach is to arrange each image's pixels in data frame columns where each columns represents time and rows are pixels in time and apply wavelet transform on each row (as 1-D signal with different mother wavelets). I expect higher coefficients where the mother wavelet matches the signal. As I do not have any experience with Wavelet Analysis, I wish to ask:

1. Is it possible to use all the images as a 3D stack and obtain temporal information with wavelet or some filtering?
2. How wavelets are chosen for any wavelet transform analysis?

Comment: your standard deviation seems to be quite a reasonable method, why not go with this? What exactly motivates the wavelets?

Comment: A threshold of standard deviation will have to be set manually which would be specific to this time series. Instead if it can be detected with wavelets I will be able to apply it to other datasets as well.

Comment: the question here is why the wavelet method would be more robust than the stddev method! I do advise that you just try, but honestly, if you just want to detect how much something is changing, the literal statistical measure of average change is not the worst approach.